# How do I tell mock to call the original method under certain circumstances?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, stub

I have a class that would want to mock later in a test:

```
class Original {
  function calculate($a) { ... }
}
```

in test:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Original',['calculate']);
$mock->expcets($this->any())
     ->will($this->returnValueMap([ 
      [1,'ABC'],
      [2,'BCD']
      // somehow tell $mock to call the original calculate() here
);
```

I want to tell `$mock` to fall back to the original `calculate()` under certain conditions, for example if arguments do not match any of provided checks. As I understand from reading PhpUnit code the invoker just returns null if no match is found :-?

Comment: One mantra for writings tests is that you take care to keep them simple. The complicate scenario you try to achieve does not seem so I'd say. Just saying, using PHPUnit mocks/stubs for that is probably the wrong tool and instead you should write your own stub for testing for that class.

Answer (score 6):

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Original::class)
            ->setMethodsExcept(['calculate'])->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
```

This will call the original *calculate* function, no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

The point of the Mock is to not call the original as it has a dependency you can not control for the test.  When you want to actually test the calculate() function, then call a test and use the normal code with set parameters to get the response you want.

```
class Original {
  function calculate($a) { ... }
}

$mock = $this->getMock('Original',['calculate']);
$mock->expects($this->any())
     ->will($this->returnValueMap([ 
        [1,'ABC'],
        [2,'BCD']

$Orig = new Original();
$this->assertEquals(4, $Orig->calculates('2 * 2');
```

Answer (score 2):

If the mocking system you use is PHP's [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/index.html), you could also make the Mock "[partial](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#runtime-partial-test-doubles)".
When you do, all the methods that are not `shouldReceive()`d will call the original underlying method.

[From the docs:](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#partial-test-doubles)

> Partial doubles are useful when we want to stub out, set expectations for, or spy on some methods of a class, but run the actual code for other methods.

> What we call a runtime partial, involves creating a test double and then telling it to make itself partial. Any method calls that the double hasn’t been told to allow or expect, will act as they would on a normal instance of the object.

```
class Foo {
    function foo() { return 123; }
}

$foo = mock(Foo::class)->makePartial();
$foo->foo(); // int(123);

$foo->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(456);
$foo->foo(); // int(456)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by using a callback to determine the returned value. If the argument does not match any of the fixed values, do a real call:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Original',['calculate']);
$mock->expects($this->any())
 ->will($this->returnCallback(function($argument) { 
    $values = array(
        1 => 'ABC',
        2 => 'BCD'
    );
    if (isset($values[$argument]) {
       return $values[$argument];
    } else {
       return (new Original)->calculate($argument);
    }
});
```

As a side note, needing this could be a simptom of tests being too general. Every test should check how your system works in a very specific case.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Original::class)
            ->onlyMethods([
                'someOtherFunction',
                'coolFunkyFunction'
                ])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
```

This will give you a mock where only the methods you specify are mocked, so `calculate()` would not be mocked.

##### Background and Acknowledgement

[Sakis's Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428100/9528429) is good, but that method is deprecated. You can find more info about the recommended alternate strategy [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3687#issuecomment-1152765207), which is also the basis of my Short Answer response.

### Long Answer

Using the original method "under certain conditions" could mean a lot of things, and many of the possible cases are cases that are best to avoid. A case where this is useful would be when one of your public methods calls another public method in the same class.
In order to test the original `calculate` when we specifically want to and avoid testing the same functionality multiple times, I'll expand the example, write a quick test class, and go through my reasoning.

##### The Class (expanded):

```
class CoolClass {
  private OtherClass $otherClass;

  public function __construct(OtherClass $otherClass){
    $this->otherClass = $otherClass;
  }

  public function calculate(int $c) {
    //...a bunch of code you want to test to get from $c to $d
    $d = $this->megaCool($c);
    $e = $d + $this->doAFlip();
    //...lots more code to get from $e to $f
    return $f;
  }

  public function megaCool(int $a) {
    //... a bunch of code you want to test that turns $a into $b
    $c = $b + $this->doAFlip();
    return $b + 10;
  }

  //...some other public methods in the class
  
  private function doAFlip(): int {
    $x = (int)$this->otherClass->flip();
    //... more code to get from $x to $y
    return $y;
  }
}
```

##### Test Class:

```
class CoolClassTest extends TestCase {
  private OtherClass $otherClassMock;
  private CoolClass $sut; //system under test

  public function setUp(){
    parent::setUp();
    $this->otherClassMock = $this-createMock(OtherClass::class);
    $this->sut = new CoolClass($this->otherClassMock);
  }

  public function testMegaCool() {
    //...set behaviour/expectations for $this->otherClassMock called in doAFlip()
    $calculated = $this->sut->megaCool(1);
    //...maybe some assertions
  }

  //...other tests for your other public methods, which also use $this->sut

  public function testCalculate() {
    $sutForCalculate = $this->getMockBuilder(CoolClass::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['megaCool', 'someOtherPublicFunction'])
            ->setConstructorArgs([$this->otherClassMock])
            ->getMock(); 
    //...set behaviour/expectations for $this->otherClassMock called in doAFlip()
    $response = $sutForCalculate->calculate(123);
    //...maybe some assertions
  }
}
```

##### The Strategy

The primary goal of the test class is to test the system under test (CoolClass). We want the `setUp()` to reflect that goal cleanly. So, we want to mock or stub the dependency on OtherClass, and we want the system under test (CoolClass) to be the real thing. We will have other scenarios
where it's partially mocked later, but not in `setUp()`.

When we're testing calculate, we can see that it has a dependency on another public function in the class, `megaCool()`. Since we can test that class directly, we do so in a separate test, `testMegaCool()`. It's best to avoid testing the same public behaviour in multiple tests, so here is a great place to simplify `testCalculate()` by mocking its call to the method `megaCool()`.

We create a partial mock. Rather than creating the mock in `setUp()`, we create it inside `testCalculate()` so that:

- We are explicit about what is mocked, which leads to less risk than the deprecated method of silent failures from calling mocked methods by accident (at least when a real method is called by accident, it usually fails loudly).
- We have isolation from other tests and don't need to take them into consideration.
- There is no risk of other methods using it by accident and getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify only the methods to mock. In this way methods you don't specify follow the original logic:

```
    $myStubObject = $this
      ->getMockBuilder(Original::class)
      ->setMethods(["anyButCalculate"])
      ->getMock();

    $myStubObject
      ->method('calculate')
      ->withAnyParameters()
      ->willReturn("expectedResultFromOriginalLogic");
```