# How to mock inner function in phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

This is my Foo class

```
<?php


class FooClass
{
    public function doFoo($total)
    {
        $gst = (($this->getTaxRate() / 100) * $total);

        return $gst;
    }

    public function getTaxRate()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And this is my test.

```
public function fooTest()
{
    $mockedObj = $this->createMock(FooClass::class);

    $mockedObj->expects($this->exactly(1))
        ->method('getTaxRate')
        ->will($this->returnValue(10));

    $this->assertEquals(10, $mockedObj->doFoo(100));
}
```

Output:

```
Failed asserting that null matches expected 10.
```

I can see getTaxRate() function is not being mocked .It is also returning null instead of 5(default value). I am expecting getTaxRate() inside doFoo() to return the mock value i.e 10  else if I do not mock a getTaxRate, it should return 5.

Anything that I am missing here?

Comment: You're mocking the entire instance of `FooClass`. That means `doFoo()` is mocked as well, and since you haven't specified what you want it to return, it returns `null`. It never calls `getTaxRate()`. You're looking for a partial mock where `getTaxRate` is mocked but `doFoo` calls the original function. The examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944262/how-do-i-tell-mock-to-call-the-original-method-under-certain-circumstances) might be helpful.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you.